# How to enable user-level rate limiting in istio

Tags: istio

I saw [Istio site](https://istio.io/about) mention Rate Limiting support but I can only find global rate-limit example.

Is it possible to do so at user-level? For example, if my user logged in but sends more than 50 requests within a second then I'd like to block said user, etc. In a similar situation, if user doesn't logged in then that device cannot send more than 30 requests per seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to conditionally apply rate limits based on arbitrary
attributes using a match condition in the quota rule.

`apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
 name: quota
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 match: source.namespace != destination.namespace
 actions:
 - handler: handler.memquota
   instances:
 - requestcount.quota`

The quota will only apply when the source namespace is not equal to the destination namespace. In your case you probablty want to set a match like this:

`match:
  request:
    headers:
      cookie:
        regex: "^(.*?;)?(user=jason)(;.*)?$"`

I made a PR to improve the rate-limiting docs you can find it here: https://github.com/istio/istio.github.io/pull/1109