# Is there any API gateway for kubernetes which rate-limits based on client-id in jwt?

Tags: kubernetes, api-gateway, rate-limiting, kong, api-throttling

I have a list of API's running in kubernetes behind a service (under different paths). Azure is our identity provider, and our clients are using client-credentials OAuth2 flow to generate the OAuth token and send to API, where authorization checks take place. Each of our APIs needs a different SLA for each user. Hence I am looking to rate-limit the API's per client-id that is encoded in the token (`azp` is the claim under which client-id is present for Azure v2.0 tokens)

We are already using Envoy as ingress gateway in our kubernetes cluster, but that supports only global or per-ip rate-limiting. We also looked at nginx, but did not find much difference. ChatGPT suggested other gateways like Tyk and Apigee-edge, but they don't seem to have this functionality. The closest suggestion given was to use Kong gateway, which rate-limits based on consumer-groups (but I did not find anything in Kong documentation about per OAuth client rate-limiting, or how a consumer can map to client-id).

Does any API gateway support such rate-limiting feature?

Comment: this question seems similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005461/how-to-enable-user-level-rate-limiting-in-istio

Comment: Slightly similar, but in my case the oauth/jwt token in the request header will be encoded. So I will have to decode it somehow, get the client-id from the claims, and configure rate-limiting based on that. Not sure if istio allows such customized extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend nginx with Lua scripting. I've not used it for this specifically, but it occurs to me that you can run a Lua script to parse the JWT and then use the client-id as the zone key for the normal nginx rate-limiting feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65121006/8223894

Do you mean something like this?